# Sorting - LINQ vs BindingSource in a DataGridView (which is best practice?)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sorting, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to decide the best route (or best practice) to go for sorting of a DGV - Binding or LINQ.

What I would like to do is to create a method that receives parms from the user (in this case, it would be to identify the mouse click of a header and a sort direction - if sorted).  Then the method would take the parms and use them in a LINQ statement.

query = query.OrderBy(a => a.Code);

In the method, I want to replace the "OrderBy" with a variable, as well as "Code".  However, I don't have the correct syntax, nor do I know if this is even a good way to do it.  It makes sense to me so that I don't repeat code, but is LINQ a good route?

```
        var sortOrder = "OrderByDescending";
        var sortColumn = "Code";
        query = query.sortOrder(a => a.sortColumn);
```

My setup:
C# dataGridView that is populated from a database.  LINQ filtering exists in the DataAccess project.

Thank you,
Brian.

edit:   WinForms and LINQ to EF.

Comment: Web? Desktop? WinForms? WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: LINQ TO SQL? LINQ TO EF?  :D

Comment: Am I thinking of this wrong?  Should I use LINQ in backend, but in the UI, use a bindingSource since that will be a filtered list?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use Reflection like this  or [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

```
  var sortOrder = "OrderByDescending";
  var sortColumn = "Code";
  if(sortOrder =="OrderByDescending")
     query = query.OrderByDescending(a => GetPropertyValue(a,sortColumn));
  else 
     query = query.OrderBy(a => GetPropertyValue(a,sortColumn));



private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string property)  
{  
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo=obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);  
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);  
}
```